# wkhtmltopdf + mixed photo colors

Tags: image, wkhtmltopdf, grayscale

I have a page with color and black & white images, when I use wkhtmltopdf to generate a pdf from the html file,

I get only the color images, how can I get it to print all the images, I have tried the advance options, but no success.

If I print in grayscale, then all the images are coming, but I don't want grayscale.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to solve this problem, I tried a trial-and-error method and figured out that if we provided the following parameters all the images irrespective of color or B&W, it would come up

wkhtmltopdf --image-quality 75

NOTE: Any value <= 75 works, higher value print a blank space for B&W images only

Comment: This worked for me also... but with a value of 55. Very strange

Comment: This only helps some images. I still have many cases where images are blank. Furthermore, some viewers (Adobe on win7) actually prevent you from printing due to the corrupt embedded images. I'm currently trying to fix this issue with the developer -- will post a real fix when resolved.

Answer (score 2):

This question is old, but I'll add this in case someone has a similar issue and is unable to upgrade.

I found that applying this CSS solved the problem of non-color image rendering for me.

img {opacity: 0.99;}

Answer (score 1):

To follow on from my comment above:

- Changing the image quality only helps some cases
- I contacted the developer (antialize) and he has now fixed this issue on his staging branch.

There isn't a release yet with this fix, so you will have to compile it yourself.

If you [compile](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation) using the latest **staging** branch, all images now work as expected. Remember to compile following the "Installing QT yourself" instructions.

Furthermore, if you want to compile statically, see my note (on the [compilation wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation), made on Dec 19, 2011) about editing two files to allow static compiling of webkit (the 2 files that need to change are `/tools/configure/configureapp.cpp` and `configure`).