# Wkhtmltopdf cuts off images

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

So I have had my share of problems with images and wkhtmltopdf. I am trying to convert [this html (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/vqpmjypo/), to a pdf using wkhtmltopdf (0.12.2.1). However, wkhtmltopdf crops my potato.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make it stop cropping my potato?

I already applied a hack to the html in order to get images to display properly. After extensive research I found that wkhtmltopdf doesn't like clip-path, so I replaced all clip-path's with `clip-path="none"`. Then my images worked, until now that I try to `text-align:center` them.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: have you tried it without an svg and just an image to see if wkhtmltopdf is having issues with large svg?

Also can you paste what options you are passing to wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 2):

When I found this I hoped I would find the answer to this very issue.

I found the answer at the bottom of this question: [wkhtmltopdf + mixed photo colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718660/wkhtmltopdf-mixed-photo-colors#)

Check out @catchdave's response almost 4 years after the OP.

TL&DR, for whatever reason, you need to add `opacity: .99` to your image css.

Hope this helps others as I wasted 2 full days debugging this issue before I found the solution!